# sizeWithFont: constrainedToSize: with UITextView is (sometimes) not creating correct height - iPhone

Tags: iphone, height, uitextview, frame

I am using the following code to determine the height needed for a `UITextView` that is being added to a `UITableViewCell`, and also to determine the height for each `UITableViewCell`.

This works 90% of the time, but some incoming data (always the same incoming data) comes up short. If I allow scrolling within the `UITextView`, I can see that all the text is in the `UITextView` - but the `UITextView` does not have enough height to display all the text.

There does not appear to be anything wrong with the text that is being read, no special or hidden characters, etc.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14];
CGSize withinSize = CGSizeMake(230, 10000); 
CGSize size = [currentTimelineText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:withinSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

When I then create a frame with `frame = CGRectMake(boundsX, yPosition, 230, size.height);` and assign that `frame` to the `UITextView` , it (sometimes) comes up short.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

don't use `UITextView`. seems TextView have margin&padding configured by apple.
using `UILabel` instead. (don't forgot to set EnableMultiLine to YES).

Comment: And, it's not a padding issue. I am using myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-8, -8, 0, 0); so the text is positioned at the top left of the UITextView

Answer (score 2):

If table is in group mode, watch out for paddings. At the time of cellForRowAtIndexPath or heightForRowAtIndexPath, cell has screen width, not with padding of group style table.

Comment: Maybe not the answer for this question, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!