# SizeWithFont of Text With Justification applied?

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Is there a way to calculate the size of the justified text in Xcode.I am using a uitextview to show my text and I don't want the text to appear in more than 11 lines.There are methods like 
sizewithfont I have used them but even after calculating the size and only populating the 
uitextview with the specific amount of text when I apply NSTextAlignmentJustified more lines 
are produced than actual ones ! 
Is there a way to calculate sizewithfont with justification ????

Comment: Please refer below link , May be helpful to You. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596028/sizewithfont-constrainedtosize-with-uitextview-is-sometimes-not-creating-cor

Comment: Thanks ! but this doesn't answer my question.The problem is still there , I have googled a lot about this issue  , there is no way to calculate the width of justified text !